# go mustache how to output '%'?

Tags: go, mustache

Html template code:
`<button type="button" style="width:80%;">asasas</button>%`

It will be output by mustache as following:
`<button type="button" style="width:80%!;(MISSING)">asasas</button>%!(NOVERB)`

It's unexpected, How to fixed it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly that looks like a bug in the library, since printf-like `%` specifiers aren't part of the mustache language, but most likely the way to get a % in the output is to use `%%` in the template.